# nest-device-access payment error with credit card

Tags: console, device, payment-processing, fee

I am trying to set up my personal Google account with nest-device-access. I am following the instructions and I am trying to pay the one time $5.00 fee.

I am going to this page: https://console.nest.google.com/device-access/tos and when I click on the "Continue to Payment" button in order to complete the one-time-fee, a list of my payment method is presented.
None of the are working.
I select of of my credit cards and  after been asked for the verification code from the bank, the following error appears "An unexpected error has occured. Please try again later [OR-RWE-02]"

[error OR-RWE-02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUY54.jpg)

My google account is in good standing. I have multiple payment method active and the information is valid because I have active monthly subscriptions.

I also get in touch with the bank and they told me that the problem seems to be related to the strong authentication method applied which is not compliant to PSD2 required into the CE

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this the correct place where to post this error? I am asking because google support link to stackoverflow....

Comment: ...this problem is really frustrating and blocking! It seems that no one has encountered the same error, but I have asked friends and colleagues with Google accounts to process the payment (with their own accounts) and no one is able to complete the transaction.
The reason is always the same: unauthorized transaction due to non-compliance with the PSD2 strong authentication criteria.
Google Support is unable to answer as they only deal with credit card transactions from the Google Pay app and above all invite us to ask for support here at StackOverflow